# How to get form_state values in _webform_render_component

Tags: ajax, webforms

I am making a custom component for the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.
One of my elements triggers an ajax call to update the possible values of another field.
In `_webform_render_elem_courses($component, $value=null, $filter=true)`:

```
$semester=isset($value[0]) ? $value[0] : null;
$form=array(
    '#type'=>'fieldset',
    '#weight'=>$component['weight'],
);

$form['semester']=array(
    '#title'=>t($component['extra']['title_semester']),
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#options'=>_get_semesters(),
    '#default_value'=>$semester,
    '#empty_value'=>null,
    '#required'=>true,
    '#ajax'=>array(
        'callback'=>'semester_callback',
        'wrapper'=>'courses',
    ),
);

$form['courses']=array(
    '#prefix'=>'<div id="courses">',
    '#suffix'=>'</div>',
    '#type'=>'checkboxes',
    '#options'=>_get_courses($semester),
    '#default_value'=>isset($value[1]) ? $value[1] : array(),
    '#required'=>true,
);
return $form;
```

In semester_callback($form,$form_state)

```
$element=$form_state['triggering_element'];
$parentCount=count($element['#parents']);
$component=$form;
for($i=0; $i<$parentCount-1; $i++){
    $component=$component[$element['#parents'][$i]];
}
return $component['courses'];
```

The problem that I am having is that $value is not populated with anything when the ajax is triggered, so there is no way for me to update the 'courses' element based on the 'semester' element. Is there a way to fix or get around this?